# How do I select element from same table row on change function using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a jquery code where I want to select another select element on choose of the first select element but it couldn't select why...?

here is table

```
<table id="travelDetailTbl" class="table table-list table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;">
<tbody id="row_div">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="travelMode[]" id="travelMode1" class="form-control travelMode">
                <option value="0">Travel Mode</option>
                <option value="171">By Air</option>
                <option value="172">By  Train</option>
                <option value="173">By Road</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="travelClass1" name="travelClass[]" class="form-control travelClass">
                <option value="0" selected="">Select Travel Class</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



$('#travelDetailTbl').delegate(".travelMode","change",function(){
    alert("hello");
    $(this).closest('.travelClass').remove();
});
```

here alert is working properly. i just want to just select that particular element later I will perform operations.

Comment: How could we possibly know, without knowing what HTML resp. DOM structure you are running this on …? Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: please check now

Comment: `.closest` goes up in the DOM tree to try and find the element you make it look for. There is no `.travelClass` element further up the tree, from the position of your `.travelMode` element. You need to go up to the TD or the TR first, and then select your way sideways/down to the element you want.

Comment: yes you right its working now thanks..

Comment: please post it on answer. if any one search it may he get his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest` goes up in the DOM tree to try and find the element you make it look for. There is no `.travelClass` element further up the tree, from the position of your `.travelMode` element.

You need to go up to the TD or the TR first, and then select your way sideways/down to the element you want.